# How to wireless connection available only to command prompt?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet

As in my office, the ethernet connection is full of restrictions, therefore I use my smart phone to provide a portable Wi-Fi hotspot, by which I connect and install packages using command prompt freely without any restrictions ..

That's cool, but how can I avoid any connection via my phone other than the command prompet?

I need to make sure that ONLY the command propet uses my smart phone Wi-Fi, while any other connection uses the available ethernet connection.

I am on Windows 7 home premium.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a program called [ForceBindIP](http://www.r1ch.net/stuff/forcebindip/) that does what you are looking for. From that page:

> ForceBindIP is a freeware Windows application that will inject itself
> into another application and alter how certain Windows Sockets calls
> are made, allowing you to force the other application to use a
> specific network interface / IP address. This is useful if you are in
> an environment with multiple interfaces and your application has no
> such option for binding to a specific interface.
>
> ...
>
> Some programs that have been tested to work with ForceBindIP include
> DC++, uTorrent, Quake II, Quake III, Diablo II, StarCraft, Internet
> Explorer, Mozilla Firefox, Google Earth, Infantry, Real Player, Unreal
> Tournament 2004 (requires -i), Outlook 2000 (requires -i). Programs
> that do not work include GetRight (anti-debugger / forking
> techniques), WinCVS (forks cvs.exe)

It only works on 32-bit Windows systems so that might be an issue for you.

Comment: hmm, strange that it works only on 32-bit windows .. it seems to be an old software ..

Comment: It does look pretty old. It works by intercepting calls to socket DLLs. Those most likely have changed in 64bit Windows which is why it only works on 32bit. I've not used it but it's the only thing I've seen that would address your question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can assign a internet connection to a particular application. You can use a virtual machine that will have its own separate internet connection via its own Ethernet device.

a proxy or ssh tunnel is also a good solution, but I don't think this is possible with the windows command prompt, which probably draws its internet feed from whatever all other applications use, I've never heard of it using a proxy... then again, i've also never heard of "downloading packages" in command prompt on windows.

Comment: I am using command prompt to install node modules (npm install socket.io ) .. like if I am at ubuntu ..

Comment: But, first, I have to provide the env paths .. to find the installed app